# 32 vs 64 bit Outlook with 32-bit application - different results

Tags: outlook-redemption

I've got a strange situation in hand where the redemption com object is giving different results on different similar machines. We're kind of stuck in resolving the cases.
(i know this topic may be vague or missing information, please forgive me for that - i most certainly will try to add information as soon as it is available)

We have a 32-bit application and use the 32-bit version of Outlook Redemption to read emails whilst using a 64-bit version of Outlook.
On one of the systems, when the object is created in Appeon PowerBuilder it succeeds and the outlook inbox can be read.
The other system throws a generic PowerBuilder OLE error "-3 -- Object could not be created".
Both systems are Windows 2022-server with Microsoft® Outlook® LTSC MSO (16.0.14332.20587) 64-bit running in a RDS environment.

Reading through the [FAQ](https://dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm) on the website I did notice the bitness remarks but the behaviour on one of the servers is the exact opposite of what I would expect - it does work on one of the servers with 32-bit application/dll + 64-bit outlook.

The non-functioning server previously did work too - something must have changed but as these servers are kept up-to-date constantly I can't be sure and would like some pointers.

Is there something I can do to debug/troubleshoot this case ?

Thanks!

- Debug-application in C# but this correctly follows the bitness guidelines with both 64 and 32 bit redemption. it works for 64 bit but not 32-bit
- Re-register the most recent (6.4.0.6324) version of Redemption with regsvr32 and fall-back to a previous version of Redemption (5.5.0.3218) version that we used previously with success.
- The connection to outlook seems to succeed but the subsequent `li_result = iole_olSafeApp.ConnectToNewObject("Redemption.SafeMailItem")` call seems to fail.

Comment: Do you mean you get an error when creating an instance of a Redemption object? Or when creating an instance of the Outlook.Application object?

Comment: The  creation of the Outlook.Application object seems to succeed however the call to create the Redemption.Safe*item fails.  (edited in question too)

Comment: Send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com, and I will provide the debug version of the dll.